# What is the best/proper configuration? (javascript SOAP)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, web-services, soap

I need to retrieve data from a web service (via SOAP) during a nightly maintenance process on a LAMP server. This data then gets applied to a database. My research has returned many options and I think I have lost sight of the forest for the trees; partially because of the mix of client and server terms and perspectives of the articles I have read.

Initially I installed node.js and node-soap.  I wrote a simple script to test functionality:

```
var soap = require('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/soap');
var url = "https://api.authorize.net/soap/v1/Service.asmx?WSDL";
soap.createClient(url, function(err, client)
{
  if(typeof client == 'undefined')
  {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
  console.log('created');
});
```

This uses a demo SOAP source and it works just fine. But when I use the actual URL I get a 5023 error:

```
[Error: Invalid WSDL URL: https://*****.*****.com:999/SeniorSystemsWS/DataExportService.asmx?WSDL
Code: 503
Response Body: <html><body><b>Http/1.1 Service Unavailable</b></body> </html>]
```

Accessing this URL from a browser returns a proper WSDL definition. I am told by the provider that the 503 is due to a same-origin policy violation. Next, I researched adding CORS to node.js.  This triggered my stepping back and asking the question: **Am I in the right forest?** I'm not sure. So, I am looking for a command-line, SOAP capable, CORS app (or equivalent) configuration. I am a web developer primarily using PHP and Javascript, so Javascript is where I turned first, but that is not a requirement. Ideas? Or, is there a solution to the current script error (the best I think I have found is using jQuery in node.js which includes CORS)

Comment: The same-origin policy would only make sense if you're running the SOAP retrieval code in the browser ([reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)). The server shouldn't return a 503 unless it's truly unavailable. CORS is also only for web browsers, and doesn't apply to NodeJS code ([reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)).

Comment: I agree, the WSDL URL opens fine in a browser, so I am not convinced it is a true 503.  Perhaps there is a problem with the node.js/node-soap. This is the reason for my post, before diagnosing a somewhat suspicious error code I want to be sure I am using the best platform for the job.  See my reply post below - I think I have found a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have a better approach to the task.  I found over the weekend that PHP has a full SOAP client.  I wrote the same basic login script in PHP and it runs just fine.  I get a valid authentication code in the response to loginExt (which is required in further requests), so it looks like things are working.  I will comment here after verifying that I can actually use the web service.

Comment: PHP SOAP is working very nicely.  The biggest hurdle is working out the data format of parameters. As a bonus, it fits the existing language choice of the system (PHP).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, this error belongs to your website server.
Please go through this link, it might be helpful.

http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/503error.htm

Also you can open your wsdl in web browser, search for soap:address location tag under services. And figure out correct url, you are trying to invoke from your script. Directly access this url in browser and see what are you getting.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not my server - I have no access to it at all.  I have directed the provider to this conversation and will let them determine if this is truly a problem.

Comment: Then how are you supposed to access this webservice, if you dont have credentials?

Comment: Sorry, I read too much into your replay "this error belongs to your website server".  I have no access to the server backend, so no logs, no config files, etc.  As I stated in my original post, the URL opens a full, proper WSDL definition when accessed thru a web browser.  The error occurs when accessing thru the SOAP script.